# How to use Boost.Beast library

Tags: c++, boost, beast

I want to use Boost.Beast

https://github.com/boostorg/beast

and I put header to C file.

sample.c

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
```

and compiled it.but not working

```
$ gcc sample.c
sample.c:1:10: fatal error: boost/beast.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <boost/beast.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How to solve this? Teach me please.

*later add
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Intel

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
$ cd beast/
$./bootstrap.sh
$vim sample.c
$ gcc sample.c
sample.c:1:10: fatal error: boost/beast.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <boost/beast.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions here](https://github.com/boostorg/beast#github)?

Comment: Yes


```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
$ cd beast/
$./bootstrap.sh
$vim sample.c
$ gcc sample.c
sample.c:1:10: fatal error: boost/beast.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <boost/beast.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: shouldn't you add `-I./include` to the gcc command, and then also the library search path and the library too. Also I'm pretty sure beast is a C++ only library and doesn't have a C Interface, not sure though

Comment: okay thank you , I want to use Beast to run C code but may no C language interface in Beast.

Comment: Beast (and pretty much all of boost) won't work in c, you'll need to use c++. The easiest way for you to use boost is probably just to install it from apt rather than building it yourself